# Continuity of a function in $(x,y)$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

So this is my fucntion: $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2-x\sqrt{y}}{x^2+y}; &x,y \neq (0,0)\\0 ;&x,y=(0,0) \end{cases}$$
I tried to find the limit at $(0,0)$ using $y=mx$ and substituting in the equation to get $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2-x\sqrt{mx}}{x^2+mx}$$ leading to nowhere. Isn't this the right approach? Need some guidance here.

Comment: What's the domain of the function?

Comment: Let $y = 0$ and see what happens.

Comment: @user58697 so limit will be 1. but how I show limit is same for other directions as well..

Comment: The limit is $1$, but the function value is $0$ (by definition).

Comment: @user58697 oh yess! thanks. i am so dumb sometimes

Comment: In general you use paths to disprove continuity,  to prove continuity if all the paths you try (lines,  squares,   cubes, etc.) are the same you then generally use something like the squeeze theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can start with letting $y=0$ since that won't give you any issues, but you can actually continue with what you did:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2-x\sqrt{mx}}{x^2+mx}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x(x-\sqrt{mx})}{x(x+m)}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\sqrt{mx}}{x+m}=\frac{0}{m}=0$$

for $m \neq 0$.

As you can see (since when you choose the path along $y=0$ the limit is $1$), this means the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: So its was easy to fall trap there by concluding limit is $0$ for any $m$. Thanks for pointing out!